# ember-cli: creating a helper that would render a view?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, emblem.js

I'm trying to reproduce Ember-TodoMVC with ember-cli. I'm stuck with [this part](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/accepting-edits/).

I've created a view like this:

#### app/views/action-edit.coffee

```
ActionEditView = Ember.TextField.extend
  didInsertElement: -> @$().focus()

`export default ActionEditView`
```

When i use it in an Emblem template directly, e. g. `view "action-view"`, it works fine: a text field is rendered.

But emberjs.com/guides suggests creating a helper to render the view.

I found this remark: "Remember that you must register your helpers by exporting makeBoundHelper" on ember-cli website. After fiddling for a while struggling to understand how ES6 modules work, i ended up with this code that does not produce any JS errors:

#### app/helpers/action-edit.coffee

```
`import ActionEditView from 'loltodo/views/action-edit'`

`export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(ActionEditView)`
```

When i use it like this in an Emblem template: `action-edit`, Ember outputs this in browser console:

> [✓] helper:action-edit ......................................... loltodo/helpers/action-edit vendor/ember/ember.js:3521

So i assume the helper gets hooked up fine.

The problem is that it renders blank!

I also tried this:

#### app/helpers/action-edit.coffee

```
`import ActionEditView from 'loltodo/views/action-edit'`

`export default Ember.Handlebars.helper('action-edit', ActionEditView)`
```

It results in error "undefined is not a function" in [this line](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.5.1/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/ext.js#L176).

So the question is: how do i create a helper that render a view with ember-cli to reproduce [this step](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/accepting-edits/) of the Ember-TodoMVC tutorial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Stefan says: the docs describe this so here are the steps:

1. from command prompt run `ember generate helper "luis-highlight"`
   make sure your helper name has a dash.. `ember-cli` does not want
   conflict with html tags (if no dash then it does not work).
2. inside `helpers/luis-hightlight.js` write this:

   ```
   import Ember from 'ember';

   export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(value) {
     return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('<span class="hightlitht">' + value + '</span>');
   });
   ```
3. call helper from template:

   ```
   {{luis-hightlight 'embercli is great'}}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

consider looking at: https://github.com/WMeldon/ember-cli-todos/blob/master/app/components/edit-todo.js it should have an idiomatic ember-cli todo setup

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Stef. I know that this can be done with components and i do plan to use them. But my goal here is not to implement a task but rather learn how do to certain thing (suggested by emberjs.com/guides) with ember-cli. Can you suggest how to do a "custom view helper" with ember-cli? http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#toc_custom-view-helper-example

Comment: I'm running into the exact same problem.  Does ember-cli support custom view helpers?  The documentation would make it seem not.